# CSS align outside of div

Tags: html, css

I have a code [of navigation](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6m8vw5jy/) where navigators align to left inside div

But how to align to same position but outside this div so rounded corners must be on left ( now they on right ) to get something like this
[image]

I cant remove `overflow:hidden` because i have slider and if i remove it all slides goes out of div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `overflow:hidden` form outer div and put `left:-48px;` for the buttons.

[**Fiddle**][1]

https://jsfiddle.net/6m8vw5jy/

Comment: But what if i cant remove overflow:hidden because i have slider and if i remove it all slides goes out of div

Answer (score 2):

What Swaranan said. And change the radius from right to left:

https://jsfiddle.net/6m8vw5jy/1/

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to delete overflow:hidden, it prevents the display of you nav outside of the parent's div.

Comment: I cant remove overflow:hidden

Comment: Then I think you should find a new configuration for your nav. overflow:hidden will allways cut the content which overflow the parent.

Answer (score 2):

i took out navigation id from div first1 and moved left for 48px, and changed css for rounds :

border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;

```
<div style="position: relative; top: 100px; left: 100px; width: 700px; height: 700px; background: #fff; overflow: hidden;">

<div>
    <ul id="navigation">
            <li class="ZoomIn" id="ZoomIn"><input type="button" title="ZoomIn"/></li>
            <li class="ZoomOut" id="ZoomOut" style="display:none"><input type="button" title="ZoomOut"/></li>
            <li class="Download" id="Download"><input type="button" title="Download"/></li>
            <li class="Play" id="Play" style="display:none"><input type="button" title="Play"/></li>
            <li class="Stop" id="Stop"><input type="button" title="Stop" /></li>
</ul>
    </div>

    <div id="first1" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 48px; width: 500px; height: 500px; background: #191919; overflow: hidden;">

</div>
</div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul#navigation {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 10px;
    left:0px;
    list-style: none;
    z-index:5001;
}
ul#navigation li {
    width: 50px;
}
ul#navigation li input {
    display: block;
    margin-left: -2px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;

    background-color:#5267ff;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    border:1px solid #AFAFAF;
    -moz-border-radius:0px 10px 10px 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    /*-moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 3px #000;
    */
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=60);
}

ul#navigation .ZoomIn input{
    background-image: url(../img/icons/SliderJssor/ZoomIn.png);
}
ul#navigation .ZoomOut input{
    background-image: url(../img/icons/SliderJssor/ZoomOut.png);
}
ul#navigation .Download input     {
    background-image: url(../img/icons/SliderJssor/Download.png);
}
ul#navigation .Play input     {
    background-image: url(../img/icons/SliderJssor/Play.png);
}
ul#navigation .Stop input     {
    background-image: url(../img/icons/SliderJssor/Stop.png);
}
```

Comment: I need navigation button should be inside div as all this div zoomIn together with navigation buttons, if navigation button is outside div then zoomIn only div without navigation buttons

Comment: but you can create another div (call it container) which will contain zoom-in div and the navigation button and then you can implement zoom-in in div container

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6m8vw5jy/2/

You need to update the left: property fix the z-index and remove overflow: hidden.